# How to show project structure in project tool window

Tags: intellij-idea

Today I have started my IDEA and my cat ran over the keyboard. Now I can not see the structure in my project tool windows. I just see the structure over the window. This is not really comfortable.
I checked out the settings from this windows and try to find the shortcut in IDEA guidelines. But I can not find it.

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.2
Build #IU-145.971, built on April 29, 2016
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok... I found it.. I have no idea what happens, but I i belive that my cat is completly innocent.

The modul was missing.
Here the solution:

[image]

And than add your project path to the modul.

[image]